# Re-Indexing Bits Within a Char

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have an exercise where I have to encode and decode strings at the bit level that are given in by the command line.

The caveat for this is that I have to use a permutation mapping to re-order the bits.

Here's an Example:

The User Inputs The Character To Encode

```
 H
```

The Binary for H is

```
 01001000
```

However, that is the regular mapping of the 8 bits, through 0-7.

My program will have to permute the bits to whatever Mapping Patter I use.

For Example, If I use Mapping 64752031

The Bits for the Char 'H'

```
01001000
```

Turn To

```
01000001
```

When encoding the char, the 0th bit turns to the 6th bit, the 2nd bit turns to the 4th bit, the 3rd bit turns to the 7th bit, and so on. Whatever is based on for that mapping.

Is there a way that I can manipulate and change the order of bits based on the permutation map given?

Thank you.

Comment: What about the first bit?

Comment: In the number `64752031` is the `6` for least significant or the most significant bit? How to interpret the mapping?

Comment: The 0th bit would would now be the 6th bit in the binary for the Char 'H'. So it would be the 6th bit would be now the first bit

Comment: @gooddayjay One more is zero bit less significant bit of the character? In other words are you counting bits from left to right or from right to left?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to process large strings, it is probably better to use a look-up table that will precompute the translation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char perm[256];  // permutation table
unsigned mapping[8]={6,4,7,5,2,0,3,1};
// assumes    7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
//       =>   6 4 7 5 2 0 3 1

void mkperm(unsigned char perm[256]) {
  for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
    perm[i]=0;

  for (int i=0;i<256;i++) {
    for (int j=7; j>=0; j--) {
      int pos=mapping[7-j]; // at mapping[0] is the new position of bit 7
      if (i & (1<<j))       // only considers set bits, the table is previously cleared
        perm[i] |= (1<<pos) ;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  mkperm(perm);
  printf("%.2x => %.2x\n",'H',perm['H']);
}
```

`mkperm()` computes the permutation table by scanning the successive bits of every char. If a bit is set in char i, we set at position i in the translation table a bit at one at a logical weight given by the mapping. Setting this one is done by oring the content of cell i with a 1 properly shifted.

Comment: Great approach. Something I never thought really.

Comment: Is there any possible way to input a larger string then just 'H'? Like what If I wanted to input a sentences, how could this be done?

Comment: Just loop over the chars in your string and convert every char encountered. Assume you want to transform string "before" to "after". You just have to do `int i; for (i=0; before[i]; i++)  { after[i]=perm[before[i]];  }` The loop will stop when `before[i]=='\0'`  (null terminated string) and every char of 'after' will get a permuted version of the corresponding char in 'before' thanks to the look up table 'perm'. Do not forget to add a terminating '\0' at the end of 'after' (`after[i]='\0';`).

Comment: I understand that, however, when on line 23, you do printf("%.2x => %.2x\n", 'H', perm['H']); which prints out a permed 'H'. How would you print the statement with larger strings?

Comment: Include the printf() in a loop, and replace both 'H' in the printf by `before[i]` if `before` is the string to convert and `i` the loop index.

Answer (score 1):

Use bitwise operators.

Here's an example of how to move the second bit to the seventh bit:

```
x |= (x & 1<<1) << 6;
x &= ~(1<<1);
```

If my bit numbering bothers anybody, I'm sorry. This is just how I read binary numbers.

You can also put this into an inline function:

```
inline int bit_mode(int *x, int bit1, int bit2)
{
    *x |= *x & (1<<(bit1-1)) << (bit2-1);
    *x &= ~(1<<(bit1-1));
    return *x;
}

int a;
bit_mode(&a, 2, 7);
```

Comment: OP is not trying to swap bits.

Comment: I have two versions, which should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Just shift the bits to proper positions. After some fun, I think I've got this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * A little helper function
 * get the bit number 'as' from the byte 'in'
 * and put that bit as the number 'num' in the output
 */
static inline
uint8_t map_get_bit_as(uint8_t in, 
  uint8_t num, uint8_t as)
{
  return (!!(in & (1 << as))) << num;
}

uint8_t map(unsigned long mapping, uint8_t in) 
{
  // static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8, "are you insane?");

  const int bit0 = mapping / 10000000 % 10;
  const int bit1 = mapping / 1000000 % 10;
  const int bit2 = mapping / 100000 % 10;
  const int bit3 = mapping / 10000 % 10;
  const int bit4 = mapping / 1000 % 10;
  const int bit5 = mapping / 100 % 10;
  const int bit6 = mapping / 10 % 10;
  const int bit7 = mapping / 1 % 10;

  return
    map_get_bit_as(in, 0, bit0) |
    map_get_bit_as(in, 1, bit1) |
    map_get_bit_as(in, 2, bit2) |
    map_get_bit_as(in, 3, bit3) |
    map_get_bit_as(in, 4, bit4) |
    map_get_bit_as(in, 5, bit5) |
    map_get_bit_as(in, 6, bit6) |
    map_get_bit_as(in, 7, bit7);
}

int main() {
  printf("%#02x %#02x\n\n", 'H', map(64752031, 'H'));
}
```

will output:

```
0x48 0x41
```

tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/ScratchyLargeNumericalanalysis).

Comment: Whoa. Don't you think you should give some hints instead of just giving the complete answer?

Comment: Well, there is even some [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211842/hint-only-mostly-hint-answers-desirable-or-not) on it. I think, it would be definitely nice to encourage others including OP to find a solution by themselves by giving hints. I just though of it as a fun challenge and proceeded to solve it. But I think I agree with "A hint is by definition intentionally not providing an answer to the question". To the question "Is there a way...?" - I answer: yes and to prove it, here is example way of doing it.

Comment: Do you think you could explain why you have the const int bit0 through bit7 modded by 10 for each of the bit?

Comment: JL2210, it's from a practice book I'm reading for over the summer

Comment: @gooddayjay I love those, especially when they provide a bit of difficulty.

Comment: @gooddayjay I need to convert `64752031` into `bit0=6; bit1=4; bit2=7; bit3=5; ...` (this could be an array ;) ), ie. extract numbers at decimals positions. Because I chose for the input to be just an integer number (you didn't specify the input format. a string? an array of numbers?) I assumed the `64752031` is an `unsigned long` variable. So I need to extract the numbers from the `64752031` integer, that's why for example for `7` I need to divide by `1000000` , I get `647`, then I do mod by `10` and I get `7`.

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood the order of bits as you are counting them then the corresponding function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char encode( char c, uint32_t mask )
{
    unsigned char result = '\0';

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2 * sizeof( mask ) ; i++ )
    {
        uint32_t bit =  ( ( ( uint32_t )1 << ( CHAR_BIT - 1 - ( mask & 0xf ) ) ) & c ) != 0;
        result |= bit << i;
        mask >>= 4;
    }

    return ( char )result;
}

int main( void )
{
    uint32_t mask = 0x64752031;
    char c = 'H';

    printf( "c = %hhx\n", c );

    c = encode( c, mask );

    printf( "c = %hhx\n", c );
}
```

The program output is

```
c = 48
c = 41
```

Comment: Is there a way to reverse this encoding? Like what would be the decoded version?